# Use Custiomizer to setup meta theme color tag

Tags: php, theme-development, themes, theme-customizer

I am running into a little bit of a wall on how to achieve what I would like and could desperately use some help. My WordPress theme is built for the colors to be changed in Customizer, I have it fully functioning exactly as I need it to (Finally, JQuery Mobile doesn't interact the greatest).

Now I am running into one small issue, I am using the meta tag to define browser bar color on Android and Windows phone (Not Apple because they don't support custom colors) `<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">` This is placed in the `<head>` section inside my header.php file. I would like to grab the color from one of my color options in Customizer and put it in replace of the #000000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether you store your customizer settings as mods or options (which you define with the type parameter when [adding a setting](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference%5CWP_Customize_Manager%5Cadd_setting)) you can simply use [`get_option`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) or [`get_theme_mod`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mod) in your `header.php` like this:

```
echo '<meta name="theme-color" content="' . get_theme_mod('my_browser_bar_color','#000000') . '">';
```

This line tells to look for the mod and if it isn't there make the color black.

To make this work with js-driven live preview you will also have to add a [piece of jquery that appends](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the line to the `<head>` tag.